# Why mounted hostPath doesn't work on kubernetes of GKE

Tags: linux, nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, mount

I deployed these 2 kinds of services on GKE. Just want to confirm if the nginx data been mounted to the host.

## Yaml

### Nginx deployment

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: beats
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-data
          mountPath: /var/log/nginx
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-data
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/nginx-data
          type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

### Filebeat

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: beats
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.modules:
      - module: nginx

    filebeat.autodiscover:
      providers:
        - type: kubernetes
          hints.enabled: false
          templates:
            - condition.contains:
                kubernetes.namespace: beats
              config:
                - module: nginx
                  access:
                    enabled: true
                    var.paths: ["/var/lib/nginx-data/access.log*"]
                    subPath: access.log
                    tags: ["access"]
                  error:
                    enabled: true
                    var.paths: ["/var/lib/nginx-data/error.log*"]
                    subPath: error.log
                    tags: ["error"]

    output.logstash:
      hosts: ["logstash.beats.svc.cluster.local:5044"]

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: beats
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: filebeat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: filebeat
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: filebeat
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      containers:
        - name: filebeat
          image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.10.0
          args: [
            "-c", "/etc/filebeat.yml",
            "-e",
          ]
          env:
            - name: NODE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 0
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 200Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 100Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
              subPath: filebeat.yml
              readOnly: true
            - name: data
              mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/data
            - name: varlibdockercontainers
              mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
              readOnly: true
            - name: varlog
              mountPath: /var/log
              readOnly: true
            - name: nginx-data
              mountPath: /var/lib/nginx-data
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            defaultMode: 0600
            name: filebeat-config
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/docker/containers
        - name: varlog
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log
        - name: data
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/filebeat-data
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
        - name: nginx-data
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/nginx-data
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

## Check deploy

### Nginx

```
kubectl describe po nginx-658f45f77-dpflp -n beats

...
Volumes:
  nginx-data:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/lib/nginx-data
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
```

### Filebeat pod

```
kubectl describe po filebeat-42wh7 -n beats

....
Volumes:
  ....
  nginx-data:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/lib/nginx-data
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
```

## Check on nginx pod

```
# mount | grep nginx
/dev/sda1 on /var/log/nginx type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,commit=30)
/dev/sda1 on /var/cache/nginx type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,commit=30)

root@nginx-658f45f77-dpflp:/# ls /var/log/nginx/
access.log  error.log
```

## Check on filebeat pod

```
# mount | grep nginx
/dev/sda1 on /var/lib/nginx-data type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,commit=30)

# ls /var/lib/nginx-data
(NULL)
```

---

The `hostPath` - `/var/lib/nginx-data` doesn't work. If use `minikube`, it can work. I can use `minikube ssh` to check the path on the host.
But on GKE, how can I check the hostPath on remote machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On GKE (and other hosted Kubernetes offerings from public-cloud providers) you can't directly connect to the nodes.  You'll have to confirm using debugging tools like `kubectl exec` that content is getting from one pod to the other; since you're running filebeat as a DaemonSet, you'll need to check the specific pod that's running on the same node as the nginx pod.

The standard Docker Hub `nginx` image is configured to send its logs to the container stdout/stderr (more specifically, absent a volume mount, `/var/log/nginx/access.log` is a symlink to `/proc/self/stdout`).  In a Kubernetes environment, the base log collector setup you show will be able to collect its logs.  I'd just delete the customizations you're asking about in this question – don't create a `hostPath` directory, don't mount anything over the container's `/var/log/nginx`, and don't have special-case log collection for this one pod.

Comment: Then what to set at `var.paths: ["/**/access.log*"]`?  Is it should be `var.paths: ["/var/log/nginx/access.log*"]` to read nginx's path directly? I tried it, it doesn't work.

Comment: You should configure nginx to send the logs to stdout so you can read them in Cloud Logging: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/using-logging-your-apps-running-kubernetes-engine